# Python iter() time complexity?

Tags: python, iterator, time-complexity

I was looking up an efficient way to retrieve an (any) element from a set in Python and came across this method:

```
anyElement = next(iter(SET))
```

What exactly happens when you generate an iterator out of a container such as a set? Does it simply create a pointer to the location of the object in memory and move that pointer whenever next is called? Or does it convert the set to a list then create an iterator out of that?

My main concern is if it were the latter, it seems iter() would be an O(n) operation. At that point it would be better to just pop an item from the set, store the popped item in a variable, then re-insert the popped item back into the set.

Thanks for any information in advance!

Comment: No, iterators generally don't create lists. This is covered in the docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter

Comment: Ah I see. Would it be reasonable to assume that calling next(iter()) on a set would be similar to iterating over the set using a for loop then breaking after the first iteration? I've read that an iterator is created when an iterable is passed into a for loop, then the loop just continues until the iterator has next().

Comment: It's reasonable although the loop is going to do the exact same thing except is longer to type, read and mildly slower. The key thing to understand is that in most cases (at least, for collection classes in the standard library), the iterator implementation is provided by the object itself and is thus efficient.

Comment: Oh I wasn't implying that using a for loop would comparable (at least in terms of conciseness in code) to using iter(). I just wanted to confirm my understanding of the concept of using iter(). Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sets *are* iterable, but don't have a `.__next__()` method, so [`iter()` is calling the `.__iter__()` method of the set instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), returning an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) which *does* have the `__next__` method.

As this is a wrapper around an O(1) call, it will operate in O(1) time once declared

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

---

See also [Retrieve an arbitrary key from python3 dict in O(1) time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62177595/4541045) for an extended answer on `.__next__()`!