# Retrieve an arbitrary key from python3 dict in O(1) time

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I need to retrieve an arbitrary key from a python dictionary object. Suppose I have a dictionary `d`. What's the time complexity of the following code?

```
k = next(iter(d.keys()))
```

I get that d.key() is in O(1) time in Python 3, next() is in O(1) time. What happens to the iter()? 
Can this be done in O(1) time without using extra space? Thanks!

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626669/python-iter-time-complexity) link

Comment: Will `d.popitem()` work for you?  Has the side-effect of removing the key from the dict.

Comment: @jasonharper No, I can't remove any key.

Comment: @snatchysquid checked, and still in doubt. It's O(n) time?

Comment: yes, it is O(1)

Comment: And note, calling `.keys` is pointless. You can just use `next(iter(d))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `iter` (or other logic, such as a generator expression, declaring a generator function which delegates to the dict, using `islice`, etc..) are all some form of wrapper which adds the `.__next__()` method and some position bookkeeping to the view of the object `next()` operates on.

These largely work because [dicts *are* iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), but don't have a [`.__next__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), so `iter` et al. are calling the `__iter__` method, which returns an iterable which *does* have the `__next__` method and is a [view into the dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Each case is simply a wrapper around an O(1) call, so these will all operate in O(1) time once declared

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

---

Here's a demonstration

First create a sizeable dictionary (this may take a while on slow systems)

```py
>>> from uuid import uuid4
>>> d = {str(uuid4()):str(uuid4()) for _ in range(1000000)}
```

Show this can done directly from existing method

```py
>>> next(d.__iter__()
'1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4'
>>> type(d.__iter__())
<class 'dict_keyiterator'>
```

Further objects

```py
>>> n1 = iter(d)          # iter function
>>> n2 = (k for k in d)   # generator expression
>>> def y():              # generator delegation
...   yield from d
...
>>> import itertools
>>> i = itertools.islice(d, 1)  # slice one entry from iterable
>>> type(n1)
<class 'dict_keyiterator'>
>>> type(n2)
<class 'generator'>
>>> type(y())
<class 'generator'>
>>> type(i)
<class 'itertools.islice'>
```

Each of these can be used to read the first key

```py
>>> next(n1)
'1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4'
>>> next(n2)
'1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4'
>>> next(y())
'1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4'
>>> next(i)
'1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4'
```

Proof that these have all supplied a next method

```py
>>> dir(d)
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
>>> "__next__" in dir(d)
False
>>> "__next__" in dir(n1)
True
>>> "__next__" in dir(n2)
True
>>> "__next__" in dir(y())
True
>>> "__next__" in dir(i)
True
```

---

Finally, these can also be efficiently called in a loop until some length is reached or sliced by [`islice` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) if the first N values are wanted (rather than just the first from `next()`), but will incur some further overhead when formed into a list or such

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.islice(d, 5))
['1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4', 'a920460d-a193-455c-979c-a91fd700f927', 'aeccb371-43d1-4690-8aaa-d6de0cbe3801', '9aaf2a96-9ef4-4610-8723-8401008e190a', 'e4b450aa-50a2-409a-a5b2-ab88285eb770']
```

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(y(), 5))
['1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4', 'a920460d-a193-455c-979c-a91fd700f927', 'aeccb371-43d1-4690-8aaa-d6de0cbe3801', '9aaf2a96-9ef4-4610-8723-8401008e190a', 'e4b450aa-50a2-409a-a5b2-ab88285eb770']
>>> list(itertools.islice(n1, 5))
['1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4', 'a920460d-a193-455c-979c-a91fd700f927', 'aeccb371-43d1-4690-8aaa-d6de0cbe3801', '9aaf2a96-9ef4-4610-8723-8401008e190a', 'e4b450aa-50a2-409a-a5b2-ab88285eb770']
>>> list(itertools.islice(n2, 5))
['1273a529-d406-4076-8acc-8993f2613ad4', 'a920460d-a193-455c-979c-a91fd700f927', 'aeccb371-43d1-4690-8aaa-d6de0cbe3801', '9aaf2a96-9ef4-4610-8723-8401008e190a', 'e4b450aa-50a2-409a-a5b2-ab88285eb770']
```

---

See also [Python iter() time complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46626669/4541045) (first comment on your answer by **snatchysquid**)

Comment: Thanks, but is there an answer to my question?

Comment: @Luke Each case is simply a wrapper around an O(1) call, so these will all operate in O(1) time once declared

Comment: Oh, I see - I'd put the extended answer on the more relevant post (yours!) than the one linked in first comment ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/46626669/4541045 ), but didn't further link them

Comment: @Luke fixed! Please do suggest edits if my Answer can be made clearer!

Comment: `iter` is not a generator expression, and it returns an iterator. That iterator *may* be a generator, but in this case, it isn't.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't see where you're getting that, this tries to show that many different calls come to the same logic; eventually calling `.__next__()` from the wrapped object (which can have any internal logic it likes as long as it behaves like an iterator)