# What is the complexity of next(iter(set)) python3?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

For a set. What is the time complexity for `next(iter(S))`?
Any proof?

I know that iter() turns an iterable into iterator and suppose next() is O(1).

Comment: I'm not versed in Python but isn't this `O(1)`? Unless `iter` does an `O(n)` operation, I don't see how it would affect stuff. And I assume it returns a lazy iterator, rather than eagerly evaluate the entire sequence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python iter() time complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626669/python-iter-time-complexity)